# PHP prevent file caching in script

Tags: php, cron

I am using php scripts as cron jobs.

I have this script, which opens a CSV file , parse its content to an array, then modify it and close it.

I added this script to the crontab.

The problem is when I delete that CSV file manually from the filesystem, the script still finds it and parse the old content as if that file was somehow cached.

When I execute the script using the command line, it works properly (does not find the CSV file).

I added at the beginning of the script  clearstatcache() then  opcache_reset() but nothing works

Thank you for your help

Comment: so it works when script is called in the command line, but not in the browser or as crontab, correct? are you sure that both access the same path? did you try getcwd() to check if you're in the right directory?

Comment: Try to overwrite your CSV with an empty file instead of deleting it.

Comment: @wolfgang_rt yes I am sure I am in the right path, and I'm executing the same file. The only difference is from the command line using "sudo php script_name.php", and the other using crontab. I added logs to see what is_file returns, it always returns true even if I delete the file. But it returns false if I execute the script using cmd

Comment: @jspit my goal is not deleting the file, there is a complicated process that I am doing with that file that I cannot explain here. The process returns false results because PHP somehow caches the file.

Comment: difficult to say...maybe you can do some more debugging using file_exists(), filemtime(), or trying different fopen modes (write/read/append) to gather some more insights.
one wild guess is file permissions - maybe the script runs under a different user when executed as cron and is not able to access the file as intended. try changing owner or permissions of the file